# getting dataframe element and converting it to string object in R

Tags: r

formula_df is a dataframe that looks like so:

```
> formula_df
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  lhs_new       rhs_new                          f_new                                       type  
  <chr>         <chr>                            <chr>                                       <chr> 
1 A_rejected    D_B+D_C+D_D+G_male+Q_unqualified A_rejected~D_B+D_C+D_D+G_male+Q_unqualified binary
2 D             G_male                           D~G_male                                    multi 
3 G_male        1                                G_male~1                                    binary
4 Q_unqualified 1                                Q_unqualified~1                             binary
```

```
x <- formula_df[2,'lhs_new']

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  lhs_new
  <chr>  
1 D
```

How do I convert this to a string in R?

I tried:

```
str(x)
```

but when i call the folowing i get this:

```
class(str(x))

tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ lhs_new: chr "D"
[1] "NULL"
```

Comment: @akrun This is just base R

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking about `formula_df`

Comment: `str` in R is a utility function to view the `str`ucture of an object, do not confuse it with python's `str` function that tries to convert an object to a string.

Comment: The `lhs_new` column is *already* of type `character` (i.e., a string). What do you expect the output of this to be?

Comment: perhaps like `quote(`, it is unclear what part you want as string.,

Comment: My expected output is just the string "D" in a variable. so test <- 'D' for example

Comment: Unlist should do what you want.

Comment: You could try `unlist(x)` or `tibble::deframe(x)` or `dplyr::pull(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `class`should be on the extracted column

```
class(formula_df$lhs_new)
```

As it is a tibble, we need either `$` or `[[` as the `[` wouldn't drop the dimensions as in `data.frame` where the default option is `drop = TRUE` according to `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

> drop - logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.

```
formula_df[['lhs_new']][2]
```

---

If we check the methods for

```
methods("[")
```

it returns a vector of methods, around 150 or so and `[.tbl_df` is one of them.  By searching on `?"[.tbl_df"`, it can give more info

> Accessing columns, rows, or cells via $, [[, or [ is mostly similar to regular data frames. However, the behavior is different for tibbles and data frames in some cases:

> [ always returns a tibble by default, even if only one column is accessed.

---

Also, wrapping with `str` and assigning to an object doesn't have any effect as it is just printing to console.  According to `?str`

> str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, a `data.frame` that is indexed on both the row and column will return just the element. In R parlance, this means it "drops" the dimensions. A `tibble`, on the other hand, will not drop and will "always" be a frame until you force it in other ways.

For example,

```r
formula_df[2,"lhs_new"]
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   lhs_new
#   <chr>  
# 1 D      
as.data.frame(formula_df)[2,"lhs_new"]
# [1] "D"
```

To get the same "do not drop" behavior in R, one would do

```r
as.data.frame(formula_df)[2,"lhs_new",drop=FALSE]
#   lhs_new
# 2       D
```

Not that you want that, but I present it for perspective. Bottom line, you need to either convert to `data.frame` (not `tibble`) and subset, or use an alternate form of indexing, including

```r
formula_df[["lhs_new"]][2]
# [1] "D"
```

(as akrun just demonstrated).